# View and temp statements

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a few statements for my db but there not working.

I'm trying to create a view to show all columns but only for ones with the nulls in the `Description` column.

```
CREATE VIEW vwTableErrors 
AS 
    SELECT * FROM Inventoty;
    WHERE is Description is null
```

and I'm trying to returns back a list of all item “descriptions” into a temporary table `itemDescriptions` that are ascending. I have multiple items with same description. I’m trying to keep them from being repeated.

```
Select Description as itemDescriptions 
from Inventory  
Order by itemDescriptions asc;
```

I'm using this site as a resource but I can't figure it out for the life of me been trying for a few hours now.
[http://www.w3schools.com/](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` in `Select` to remove duplicate descriptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct view:

```
CREATE VIEW vwTableErrors 
AS 
     SELECT * 
     FROM Inventory 
     WHERE Description IS NULL;
```

Distinct Select

```
SELECT Description AS itemDescriptions 
FROM Inventory 
ORDER BY Description ASC;
```

Comment: thank you mate, i didn't realize that Distinct would do that for me.